# Accessing web elements inside iframe using phantomjs with protractor

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, protractor, webdriverjs

Can phantomjs perform actions like getText() or enterText() inside iFrame? I am using protractor to do my testing. Phantomjs can perform actions in the default frame but inside iframe the locators get timed out. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to *switch* to the iframe before you can use it. Like so...

```
browser.switchTo().frame(iframeNameOrIndex);
```

Then to switch back, you use:

```
browser.driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

The [Protractor API](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api) is a good source for this...

Also, if the iframe is from another domain you may need to add the `--web-security=no` option for phantomjs:

```
phantomjs --web-security=no spec.js
```

Comment: yes this works fine with any other browser. Just with phantomjs i am facing the issue. It is successfuly switching frames even but inside the iframe it is not being able to locate the web elements. Maybe i am missing something, still trying to debug.

Comment: @Mainak try adding explicit waits with [`browser.wait`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait) and expected conditions.

Comment: Loading is almost always problem with PhanotmJS. Try to wait for 10 seconds, and then try to access elements in iframe. If it is not working, make screenshot with PhantomJS, and see weather iframe is loading.

Comment: No good still. Checked the screenshot, the iframe was loaded and also ran in debug mode, where the switch to frame passed but failed when did a find element/ wait for a condition. Any leads on how to implement htmlunit driver with protractor? It can be used instead of phantomjs as well right?

Comment: Is your iFrame on a different domain? try using the `--web-security=no` option. I updated my answer with this too.

Comment: @Brine already done that. Using the following 'phantomjs.cli.args': ['--web-security=false', '--ssl-protocol=tlsv1', '--ignore-ssl-errors=yes', '--webdriver-loglevel=DEBUG']

Answer (score 0):

Yes.. First, double-check the name of the id of the iframes using `console.log(page.childFramesName());`.. Next, you can switch the page to the iframe using `page.switchToChildFrame('name_here');`. Finally, you can do whatever you want.